# Claiming a domain name with a trademark

Tags: trademark, domain-name

I have a trademark that got issued recently. There is a domain name with that same name that appears in my trademark that I'd like to obtain. However, that domain is registered by someone but is not in use (no website shows up but it's privately registered for more than 10 years). Can I somehow use my trademark to force the registrar to hand over the ownership of that domain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relation between Trademarks and Domains?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17519/what-is-the-relation-between-trademarks-and-domains)

Comment: Probably not, especially since the person isn't violating your trademark.

Comment: By "force", no! I've got a (blank) domain that I call my lab ! And I'm using it's email for years to signup on different websites accounts... You bring your lawyers and I'll bring you a pile of printed emails and show you how it's unfair getting evicted from my own house :) Sometimes we could host professional apps with domains (ERPs/CRMs/IoT Servers...) that are in a production mode and not accessible through the domain' root path. So the term "not in use" couldn't be easily proved and even it's right it is not an act of bad faith.